# I'm writing a game of tic - tac - toe for a project, when I run PlayGame, nothing prints out, I cannot figure out why

Tags: python, object

```
class Board(object): 
    def __init__(self):
        ## board[0] denotes whoes turn it is
        self.board = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

    def putMarker(self,player,move):
        ##makes move, false if space is full
        if self.board[move].isalpha():
            return False
        if self.board[move].isdigit():
            self.board[move] = player
            return True

    def isFull (self):
        ##checks if board is full, false if not
        for i in range (1,10):
            if str(self.board[i]).isdigit():
                return False

        return True

    def score(self):
        #checks for win, false if not
        if cell[0] == cell[1] == cell[2] == 'O' or cell[3] == cell[4] == cell[5] == 'O' or cell[6] == cell[7] == cell[8] == 'O' or cell[0] == cell[3] == cell[6] == 'O' or cell[1] == cell[4] == cell[7] == 'O' or cell[2] == cell[5] == cell[8]== 'O':     
            return "The player with O's wins"
        if cell[0] == cell[1] == cell[2] == 'X' or cell[3] == cell[4] == cell[5] == 'X' or cell[6] == cell[7] == cell[8] == 'X' or cell[0] == cell[3] == cell[6] == 'X' or cell[1] == cell[4] == cell[7] == 'X' or cell[2] == cell[5] == cell[8]== 'X': 
            return "The player with X's wins"

        else:
            return False

    def __str__ (self):
        ##prints board
        return str(self.board[1]) + "|" + str(self.board[2]) + "|" + str(self.board[3]) + "\n" +"-+-+-\n" +str(self.board[4]) + "|" + str(self.board[5]) + "|" + str(self.board[6]) + "\n" +"-+-+-\n"+str(self.board[7]) + "|" + str(self.board[8]) + "|" + str(self.board[9]) 

##class Player(object): 
##  def __init__(self,name):
##      self.name = name
##      self.shape = shape
class HumanPlayer(object):
    def __init__(self,name):

        self.name = name
        self.symbol = "A" 
        self.MyScore = 0
    def name(self):
        return self.name

    def getNextMove (self, board):
        ##prompts for and executes move:
        move = input("it is your move" + self.name + "where do you want to play?")
        if board.putMarker(symbol,move):      
            board.putMarker(symbol,move)

def PlayGame(p1,p2):
   TheBoard = Board()
   p1.symbol = "X"
   p2.symbol = "O"
   while TheBoard.score == False:
       print TheBoard
       if TheBoard.board[0] == 0 and TheBoard.isFull == False:
            p1.getNextMove(TheBoard)
            TheBoard.board[0] = 1
       if TheBoard.board[0] == 1 and TheBoard.isFull == False:
            p2.getNextMove(TheBoard)
            TheBoard.board[0] = 0

    ##Display board..
    ##Ask for new move..
    ##Execute move, if false skip turn..
    ##alternate turn
```

Comment: Word of advice: try to isolate the problem as much as possible (also code wise).

Comment: You're not printing anything... If you're just running this then it doesn't look like you'll be executing anything either.

Comment: @Ben I'm sorry and thank you for pointing that out. I may delete that comment soon.

Answer (score 0):

You have to now create a module where you declare the function PlayGame as the function to be executed.

When you run the above script, it only creates all the functions, but no function really gets called.